# apple script set boot volume with 2 SSD

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks, boot, osx-yosemite

I have a Mac Pro with 2 SSD (One with Yosemite, one with Mavericks).
I need a Applescript to change the Boot-Volume from one SSD to the other and to deactivate or activate the NVIDIA-Driver.
I found a similar script for the change of Boot-Volume:

```
do shell script "bless --mount /Volumes/NAME_of_the_SSD/ --setBoot --legacy" with administrator privileges
tell application "System Events" to shut down
```

**So as a total noob in scripting Im not shure if the path is right (Volumes/Name_of_the_SSD/)**

Additional I must activate/deactivate the NVIDIA-Driver, but I think this should do it:

```
do shell script "sudo nvram boot-args="nv_disable=1"" password "xxxxxx" with administrator privileges
```

or

```
do shell script "sudo nvram boot-args="nvda_drv=1"" password "xxxxxx" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: This may not be the comment you're looking for, but won't you save a lot of time if you used a VM?

Comment: What do you mean with the VM?

Comment: Do you mean to install Windows? Or a VM in Yosemite with Mavericks in it? To clearify some things here, I am a total noob in scripting! And obvious in VM too.

Comment: I think the suggestion is that you maybe consider installing `Oracle VirtualBox` (which is free) on your Mac and then install Windows 7 (or any other junk you want to play around with) inside the Virtual Machine. That way you can keep your Mac booted in Yosemite or Mavericks or whatever decent, Apple-OS you want, but have a separate window that runs Windows **AT THE SAME TIME** without rebooting.

Comment: Maybe the first post was a little confusing, i dont need or want Windows involved. I just need the script, cause I am lazy.  Normally, If i want to boot from Yosemite to Mavericks, I have to disable the NVIDIA-Driver in the Terminal, choose the Startup-Volume with Mavericks and reboot. So I want a script of this precedure, thats it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that starting out with a 3 year old question that you don't want the answer for maybe wasn't optimal :-)  Maybe edit your question so it shows your actual situation and your actual question...

Comment: ok, clarified some things :)

Comment: Nope, I still don't get it. Can you start you question with your actual situation and your actual question... *"I have a Mac with 2 SSDs. One contains ???, the other contains ??? and I want to be able to ??? but the problem is I don't know how to ???"*

Comment: Ok, just deleted all Windows- and Old-Post-references.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
do shell script "sudo systemsetup -setstartupdisk /Volumes/Name_of_the_SSD" password "xxxxxxx" with administrator privileges
do shell script "sudo nvram boot-args=\"nv_disable=1\"" password "xxxxxxx" with administrator privileges
tell application "System Events" to restart
```